# I have a functionA within foo.py that imports another functionB within the same foo.py. Why doesn't calling functionA repeatedly import functionB?

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose I have the following file:

```
#foo.py
def functionA():
    print("a1")
    from foo import functionB
    print("a2")
    functionB()
    print("a3")

def functionB():
    print("b")

print("t1")
print("m1")
functionA()
print("m2")
print("t2")
```

Which produces the following output:

```
t1
m1
a1
t1
m1
a1
a2
b
a3
m2
t2
a2
b
a3
m2
t2
```

Here is where I see the prints are sourced from:

Which produces the following output:

```
t1 #main
m1 #main
a1 #main
t1 #import
m1 #import
a1 #import *****
a2 #import
b  #import
a3 #import
m2 #import
t2 #import
a2 #main
b  #main
a3 #main
m2 #main
t2 #main
```

On the line that I've starred, why doesn't the import attempt to run

`from foo import functionB` which repeats the process of printing "t1","m1", and "a1" again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module is cached after import, so it doesn't need to be loaded again into the scope of the function.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-module-cache